# How to make my SIP application appear in the dialog chooser when we want to make a call?

Tags: android, call, sip

Despite that I declared all this in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
 <Intent-filter>
                <Category android: name = "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <Action android: name = "android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
                <Action android: name = "android.intent.action.CALL" />
                <Data android: scheme = "tel" />
                <Data android: scheme = "sip" />
 </Intent-filter>
```